# Start heartbeat automatically on reboot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, heartbeat

Newbie question, sorry - I've been googling 'start automatically on reboot ubuntu' and the like, but I'm not sure I've found the definitive answer.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and I would like to make sure that heartbeat starts automatically whenever the server reboots.

Currently I am running the following manually:

```
$ /etc/init.d/heartbeat start
```

How can I make sure this is called whenever the server restarts?

One answer I googled suggested:

```
$ update-rc.d heartbeat defaults
```

would do the trick - is that correct?

Comment: well, just test it ?

Comment: running `update-rc.d heartbeat defaults` says `System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/heartbeat already exist`. But then when I reboot and run `/etc/init.d/heartbeat start` it starts happily without saying it's already running. So I'm confused.

Comment: Maybe the 'defaults' command is creating the start script but not actually setting it to auto-reboot?

Comment: after restart type `ps axu | grep [h]earbeat` if you see something like `root      3024  0.0  0.1  12222 12222 ?        SLs  Nov24   0:08 heartbeat: master control process nobody    3069  0.0  0.0   5672  5668 ?        SL   Nov24   0:00 heartbeat: FIFO reader      
nobody    3100  0.0  0.0   5668  5664 ?        SL   Nov24   0:00 heartbeat: write: bcast eth1
nobody    3101  0.0  0.0   5668  5664 ?        SL   Nov24   0:15 heartbeat: read: bcast eth1` that means that hearbeat is running, you can try `service heartbeat status` after restart` also

Comment: You can use `sysv-rc-conf` to create the required links to the needed runlevels.

Answer (score 2):

Type
`update-rc.d  heartbeat defaults`

and it will be starting automaticly after reboot

if you wanna turn it off type 
'update-rc.d -f heartbeat remove`

Answer (score 2):

It should.  Basically, the startup process doesn't actually look in /etc/init.d, it looks in /etc/rc2.d (or whatever is defined as the startup run level).  The files in /etc/rc2.d should be symlinks to files in /etc/init.d:

```
$ ls -l /etc/rc2.d
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  14 Sep 19 14:13 K16nsca -> ../init.d/nsca
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 677 Mar 30  2011 README
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19 Aug 15 17:30 S10syslog-ng -> ../init.d/syslog-ng
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  23 Jul  6 20:18 S20chef-expander -> ../init.d/chef-expander
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  19 Jun 30 19:46 S20chef-solr -> ../init.d/chef-solr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Jun 30 19:46 S20couchdb -> ../init.d/couchdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 Jul 22 16:20 S20fancontrol -> ../init.d/fancontrol
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jun 30 19:46 S20jetty -> ../init.d/jetty
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  28 Jul 22 16:20 S20nagios-nrpe-server -> ../init.d/nagios-nrpe-server
```

and so on.

For Heartbeat to start up on boot, it should have a symlink along those lines.

You can create these links manually, but Ubuntu uses the update-rc.d command to manage those symlinks, so you don't have to.

Since the /etc/rc2.d directory is root-owned and permissioned, you will need to actually run:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d heartbeat defaults
```

to run the command with superuser permissions.  When it runs, it should show you the set of symlinks it will create.  In addition to the one in /etc/rc2.d, it should put similar links in the other /etc/rc?.d directories, including links in /etc/rc6.d (for example) to shut down the service as the box shuts down.

Answer (score 1):

try running the script again, some scripts just say they are started and dont complain at all. Also if I am not mistaking, what you are doing is saying run this script heartbeat, BUT you are not giving the script any arguments. (If I understand [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RcLocalHowto) correctly)

What you can do is make a script named foo with :

```
/etc/init.d/heartbeat start
```

make it executable with chmod +x

and then run the command update-rc.d foo defaults

It will run all the commands in the foo script on boot up.